# Seeking dataset which contains traffic and path network?

Tags: data, network, united-kingdom

I'm looking to purchase a road network (e.g ITN), preferably with a traffic dataset (such as ESRI Streetmap). I don't know if the road networks with integrated traffic can be joined with path networks such as OS urban paths.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Alternatively, I would purchase OS ITN and Urban Paths, and buy a traffic dataset to join with them.

Does anyone know if this is possible?